# How to select date from timestamp column in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I have table in Oracle SQL Developer like below:

```
col1
--------
2019-11-29 11:14:00.821822
2020-02-11 09:14:00.821847
```

And I would like to select only rows where date is '2019-11-29' how can I do that?

Comment: First, you need to know the data type of the column.  If properly designed, it will be either DATE or TIMESTAMP.  Both are internal, binary structures with no human recognizable format, and what you see on the screen is the result of the client program (SQL Dev in your case) having applied a TO_CHAR function to convert the internal structure to a recognizable character string.  You would do will to look up TO_CHAR (and TO_DATE) in the SQL Language Reference Manual (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
where trunc(col1) = date '2019-11-29'
```

However, that cannot use an index on `col1`.  So, it is often better to use:

```
where col1 >= date '2019-11-29' and
      col1 < date '2019-11-30'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `to_date()` or `to_char()` functions. The Oracle/PLSQL `TO_DATE` function converts a string to a date and `TO_CHAR` function converts a date to a String. The `TRUNC(date)` function returns date without the time portion.

```
select *
from myTable    
where trunc(col1) = to_date('2019-11-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

or:

```
select *
from myTable    
where to_char(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2019-11-29'
```

Comment: In terms of to_date I have error: 'Wrong arguments col1...'. In terms of to_char I have error: 'Invalid function to_char', how can I do???

Comment: Are you sure the Col1 has date data type?

Comment: I am not sure, I only know that col1 has values in the following format: 2019-11-29 11:14:00.821822

Comment: You should make sure. The col1 could be Varchar, Timestamp or Date.

Comment: I checked it, col1 is Timestamp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236683/discussion-between-rezu-and-matop).

Comment: "The Oracle/PLSQL TO_DATE function . . . "  Correction. TO_DATE is _not_ a PLSQL function.  It is a built-in SQL function.  And SQL is not the same as PL/SQL.  SQL is a descriptive language for accessing the database.  PL/SQL is a procedural language, built on ADA, that integrates itself with SQL.